# Namespaced Functions interfering with print

Tags: c++, visual-c++, namespaces

I'm new to the site and browsed several similar sounding questions but haven't found my exact problem.  I suspect I'm making elementary mistakes.  A link to an answer would be appreciated, or an explanation, and again I'm sorry if my question doesn't even match the title of the post.

For c++ on the Cxxdroid app for android and in Visual Studio C++:

I'm trying to experiment with classes and namespaces to provide flexible utility to the class.  I want to use different implementations of the same function for personal analysis of certain algorithms on data structures; namely arrays vs lists/trees and also between recursive and iterative implementations of standard procedures.  I know how to do asymptotic analysis but my stubborn mind wants real numbers.

Unfortunately, however, I can't even seem to get namespace functions to work without blowing up normal functionality.  Please note, I haven't learned c++ formally yet because I'm exploring ahead of my introductory c/c++ course.

For example:

```
#include <iostream>
namespace iterative{
    int power(int base,int expo){...}
}
namespace recursive{
    int power(int base,int expo){...}
}
int main(int argc,char* argv[]){
    int result = 0;
    int num = 3;
    int exp = 2;
    //Expecting 9 in result
    std::cout << "This prints fine" << std::endl;
    result = iterative::power(num,exp);
    std::cout << result;
    std::cout << " This number and text doesn't print" << std::endl;
    return 1;
}
```

I had a much more complex function with classes above the namespaced functions (search function for node classes inside a list/tree class) but it never worked.  Then I just threw together the above snippet and tried to print result but the std::cout never fired after my function call.

Can anyone offer insight into what I'm doing wrong here?  The first cout prints and the second wont.  Further, execution hangs during the function call; the solution keeps running until I force it to stop.

I've tried to comment out one of the namespaces while using the other.

I've tried the using keyword with the namespace_name.

I've tried passing integers without variable usage: result = power(3,2);

I've tried printing the function result directly: std::cout << power(3,2) << std::endl;

I can't seem to get it to work on either application.  I know this seems like a silly and simple question but after about a week of browsing the internet I'm inundated with very vague answers to questions regarding syntax.  Perhaps I'm just not connecting the dots to my own problem...

Is my syntax in definition wrong?
Is my syntax in calling the function wrong?
Is my syntax in variable assignment wrong?

I'm at my wits' end.

Edit:

Now I feel really stupid.

You were correct.  I didn't increment my variable in the iterative implementation, which meant it hung up on an infinite loop.  I had to print the loop to see the numbers spitting out like I'm Neo in The Matrix.  Unfortunately, I didn't test the recursive function because it felt dangerous to do so if I couldn't even get the iterative function to call first...

I was so focused on using namespaces for the first time that I never looked at the loop properly.

Thank you, and sorry for the bother.  I'm going to try to extend this experiment to namespace-defining class member functions now.

Edit2: Feel free to delete this...unless it's felt that my stupidity can help others.

Comment: The snippet appears to be fine, which means that the core of the problem may lie in the body of `iterative::power`. Please include it in your question

Answer (score 0):

Silly mistake was made:

```
...
    int power(int base,int expo){
        int i = 0;
        int retval = 1;
        while( i < expo ){
            retval *= base;
            //Never did i++; or i = i + 1;
            //Had to std::cout << retval; in loop to catch it
        }
        return retval;
    }
...
```